# Delphi TEdit onClick - Enable & Do other stuff

Tags: delphi

Good day, so I was wondering if it would be possible to do something like this:

---

On Startup TEdit(Edit1) is disabled - so Edit1.enabled := false;

When the user clicks on the TEdit it would be enabled and it would do other stuff, I have tried with the Edit1.onClick but it doesn't seem to work, since it's disabled.

Comment: Indeed, if a control is disabled, the user isn't able to interact with it. So you cannot click a disabled control. This is what the user expects, and I don't think it is a good idea to challenge this expectation. What is your "actual" problem? If you want the controls to be disabled for a while during startup while background threads do some initialization work, for instance, the right thing to do would be to enable the controls when this work is done.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Not for startup, I just wanted for the User to click the specific TEdit and that one enables and other ones don't so the User has selected the right TEdit since the values where they would be editing from would be from a different input field. This program is going into like a storage house for sorting n stuff, and yknow the people there arent the smartest sometime's so I have to make it super easy to use, and the selected fields need to be the right one I guess

Comment: Then instead of using the `Enabled` property, simply use the `Color` and `Font` properties.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thank's for the answer, I guess I'll figure something out that stands out a lot with the Color And Font properties. Thanks again :)

Comment: Le me see if I understand you correctly. You wish to gude your users to fill upe the fields in proper order. If so then this can be done by changing the color of active field as suggested by Andreas. Also don't forget about setting up the corect tab order so that your users can move through proper field order using TAB key.

Comment: But if you want to preven users from editing certain fields whose data you might have populated based on the entered tata in another field I recomend you make use of ReadOnly property instead of disabling entry fields.

Comment: Thanks @SilverWarior I'll keep this in mind!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Just set the focus to Edit1 when you show the form?

Comment: Or what you can do is hide all fields except edit1 and unhide the next field in the OnEnter event of the current component.

Comment: When a control is disabled, that gives a visual cue to the user that says, don't click me

Comment: I've frequently used the combination of making a (DB) Edit ReadOnly and setting its color to btnFace. That makes it's appearance 'disabled enough' while still allowing people to copy text, click it, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A disabled control passes through clicks to the window beneath it. IOW, you can look for clicks on the parent of the disabled edit provided the parent is enabled; acquire the position of the click and query if it's on a control.

Below is an example detecting a click on a disabled edit placed on a form. You would need to adjust accordingly if the edits are parented by another container, such as a panel.

```
procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pt: TPoint;
  Wnd: HWND;
  Control: TControl;
begin
  Pt := ScreenToClient(SmallPointToPoint(types.SmallPoint(GetMessagePos)));
  Wnd := ChildWindowFromPoint(Handle, Pt);
  if Handle <> Wnd then begin
    Control := FindControl(Wnd);
    if (Control is TEdit) and not Control.Enabled then
      Control.Enabled := True;
  end;
end;
```